# Does Volley execute UI thread operations when my app comes to the foreground?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a button that calls **requestQueue.add** method of the **Volley** library. Inside the **onResponse** method i call:

```
    popupBox.display(getString(R.string.successfulRegistration), false, true);
```

**Display** method, displays a popup window thus must be called inside UI thread.

I put a break point at the beginning of the `onResponse` method.

Immediately after clicking on the button, switch to another app and send my app to the background.

IDE stops on the break point and I get my answer from the server but my app still is in the background and there is no **exception  error**.

After about a minute, I bring my app to the foreground. After that, the message window pops up.

Is that mean, I don't need to check if I can do something related to UI thread inside the `onResponse` method because volley handles it?

Comment: response method is called on ui thread in volley

Comment: And Volley waits till the app comes to the foreground?

Comment: I don't think volley is responsible for that as its work finished after calling onResponse(). That might be handled by android itself

Answer (score 0):

`onResponse` and `onErrorResponse` are called on main thread by default unless you are trying to call them from some other tread. Volley makes the Api call on a non ui thread (non UI blocking). Volley doesn't take care of your life cycle. So, if you make a api call in an activity and close that activity, the callback are received. So, you should check whether the activity is in foreground or not.